# Imports with complex folder hierarchy

Tags: python, import, python-import

Hey I'm working on a project that has a set hierarchical modules with a folder structure set up like so:

```
module_name/
    __init__.py
    constants.py
    utils.py
    class_that_all_submodules_need_access_to.py

    sub_module_a/
        __init__.py
        sub_module_a_class_a.py
        sub_module_a_class_b.py
        useful_for_sub_module_a/
             __init__.py
             useful_class_a.py
             useful_class_b.py

    sub_module_b/
        __init__.py
        sub_module_b_class_a.py
        sub_module_b_class_b.py
```

etc etc etc...

The problem is, I can't figure out how to set up the imports in the **init**.py's so that I can access class_that_all_submodules_need_access_to.py from sub_module_a/useful_for_sub_module_a/useful_class_a.py.

I've tried looking this up on Google/StackOverflow to exhaustion and I've come up short. The peculiar thing is that PyCharm has the paths set up in such a way that I don't encounter this bug when working on the project in PyCharm, but only from other environments.

So here's one particularly inelegant solution that I've come up with. My sub_module_a/useful_for_sub_module_a/**init**.py looks like:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', '..')))

import module_name
```

This is similar in sub_module_*/, where instead of 3 '..'s it's just two (i.e. '..', '..' instead of '..', '..', '..' for the sys.path.insert line above). And then in sub_module_a/useful_for_sub_module_a/useful_class_a.py, I have to import module_name/constants.py (and others) like this:

```
import module_name.constants
from module_name.class_that_all_submodules_need_access_to import ImportantClass
```

While this solution works, I was wondering if there is a **better/more elegant way to set up the imports and/or folder hierarchy**? I'm concerned about **messing with the python system path for users** of this module. Is that even a valid concern?

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of Python import: absolute and relative, see [Python import](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html). But the first import thing is that you need to understand how python finds your package? If you just put your package under your home folder, then Python knows nothing about it. You can check this blog [Python search] (https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html).

Thus to import modules, the first thing is that let Python know your package. After knowing the locations where Python would search packages, there are often two ways to accomplish this goal:

(1) PYTHONPATH environment variable. Set this variable in your environment configuration file, e.g., .bash_profile. This is also the simplest way.

(2) Use [setuptools](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html), which could help you distribute your package. This is a long story. I would not suggest you choose it, unless you would like to distribute your package in the future. However, it worth to know it.

If you set your path correctly, the Python import is just straight forward. If you would like use the absolute import, try

```
from module_name import class_that_all_submodules_need_access_to
```

If you would like to use the relative import, it depends on which module you are now. Suppose you are writing the module `module_name.sub_module_a.sub_moduel_a_class_a`, then try

```
from .class_that_all_submodules_need_access_to import XX_you_want
```

Note that relative import supports `from .xx import xx` format only.

Thanks.

Comment: Also just copying into site packages folder is a solution :)